MongoDB $dateTrunc aggregation operator doesn't return expected value
I was using $dateTrunc on a timeseries collection to group the timeseries data from 2024-12-01 to 2024-12-07 into a single bin.
Here is the aggregate pipeline:
[
  {
    $match: {
      timestamp: {
        $gte: ISODate('2024-12-01'),
        $lte: ISODate('2024-12-07'),
      },
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        timestamp: {
          $dateTrunc: {
            date: "$timestamp",
            unit: 'day',
            binSize: 7,
          },
        }
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      timestamp: "$_id.timestamp"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      timestamp: 1
    }
  }
]

Here is the result:
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "timestamp": {
        "$date": "2024-11-30T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    },
    "count": 719,
    "timestamp": {
      "$date": "2024-11-30T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "timestamp": {
        "$date": "2024-12-07T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    },
    "count": 116,
    "timestamp": {
      "$date": "2024-12-07T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  }
]

I expect the aggregation pipeline to return a single data point that sum up 7 days value (with a timestamp starting from 2024-12-01). However, the result is not what I expected.
It would be great if anyone could provide guidance on this issue. Thank you in advance!



UPDATE
Some information about timeseries collection:

timeField -> timestamp
metaField -> tags
expireAfterSeconds -> undefined
granularity -> Hours
bucketMaxSpanSeconds -> undefined


May I ask how is the boundary defined to be on 2024-12-01? Currently the code seems to be working fine for binning the data into 7 days. Can you also attach some sample json data so we may take a deeper look?

Hi @ray, I used $match to select the date greater than or equal to 2024-12-01, then use $dateTrunc to bin the data. Here is the sample timeseries data in JSON format - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UT4n3ucU470PGy2TR5r7KB2Oa0X1gsmu/view?usp=sharing (the file is quite big so I use google drive instead of pastebin). Thank you for looking into this issue!

The issue cannot be replicated in playground. The data is always binned into the boundary starting on 11-30(and into 1 single bin). I am guessing that might have something to do with your timezone config so the data is binned into 2 different bins. You may want to examine the data like this to see what data fall into which bins

{ $gte: ISODate('2024-12-01'), $lte: ISODate('2024-12-07') } covers only 6 days, not 7! It must be { $gte: ISODate('2024-12-01'), $lte: ISODate('2024-12-07T23.59.59.999') } or { $gte: ISODate('2024-12-01'), $lt: ISODate('2024-12-08') }

For me it si not clear when unit: "day", binSize: 7 will start, it seems to be random. Maybe better use unit: "week", startOfWeek: 'sunday'

@ray thank you for trying it out. All the timestamp I used in the timeseries collection are in UTC timezone (and ISODate() default timezone is also UTC). I re-read the doc again and it mentions $dateTrunc returns the lower bound of the time period. Do you know why the lower bound timestamp is 2024-11-30 instead of 2024-12-01? Is it because of MongoDB creates fixed-size time slots starting from a reference point (Unix epoch - January 1, 1970)? (Claude.ai gave me this explanation)

@WernfriedDomscheit allows users to group timeseries data by any number of days. The user will get 7d intervals timeseries in this case. My understanding of $dateTrunc might be flawed, please correct me if I am wrong.

@tattzetey you may also want to check out $bucket. You can define the boundaries there.

If you select 7 days and you want to select by this week, then use { $group: { _id: null, timestamp: {$min: "$timestamp"} } }

Thank you for the suggestions, I will have a look at $bucket and { $group: { _id: null, timestamp: {$min: "$timestamp"} } }

Obviously 1970-01-01 is not the starting point. When you use unit: 'day' with binsize, the starting point seems to be quite random and not deterministic:
for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
   const ret = db.aggregate([
      { $documents: [ {timestamp: ISODate("2024-12-01")} ] },
      { $project: {
         _id:0, 
         binSize: `${i}`, 
         day: { 
           $dateToString: { 
             date: { 
               $dateTrunc: { 
                 date: "$timestamp", 
                 unit: "day", 
                 binSize: i } 
               }, 
             format: "%u %j" } 
           } 
         }
      }
   ]).toArray().shift();print(ret);
}

{ binsize: '1', day: '7 336' }
{ binsize: '2', day: '6 335' }
{ binsize: '3', day: '5 334' }
{ binsize: '4', day: '6 335' }
{ binsize: '5', day: '6 335' }
{ binsize: '6', day: '2 331' }
{ binsize: '7', day: '6 335' }
{ binsize: '8', day: '2 331' }
{ binsize: '9', day: '5 334' }
{ binsize: '10', day: '6 335' }
{ binsize: '11', day: '3 332' }
{ binsize: '12', day: '2 331' }
{ binsize: '13', day: '6 335' }
{ binsize: '14', day: '6 335' }
{ binsize: '15', day: '3 325' }
{ binsize: '16', day: '1 323' }
{ binsize: '17', day: '1 330' }
{ binsize: '18', day: '3 325' }
{ binsize: '19', day: '7 336' }
{ binsize: '20', day: '6 335' }

I don't see any rule!
Depending on your requirements, you need either unit: 'week', startOfWeek: 'monday' or you may have a look at $setWindowFields if you are looking for a sliding window.

Thank you for clarifying. Is this the intended behaviour or is it a bug in MongoDB aggregation pipeline? I will have a look at the $setWindowFields, thank you for the suggestion!

I guess binsize > 1 is useful only for hour, minute, second, year, month where the starting point is rather obvious.

The $dateTrunc operator calculates the bin for the specified date according to its offset from a base date.  The base date will be 2000-01-01 for any unit except "week".
The basic process would be:

subtract the base date from the date in question - will give the number of milliseconds
divide the number of milliseconds by the bin size in milliseconds, rounding down
add the result to the base date

Using the test sequence lifted from another answer, this method gives the same result:
for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
   const ret = db.aggregate([
      { $documents: [ {timestamp: ISODate("2024-12-01"),basedate: ISODate("2000-01-01")} ] },
      { $addFields: {
         ms: {$dateDiff:{startDate:"$basedate",endDate:"$timestamp",unit:"millisecond"}},
         binms: i * 86400000
      }},
      { $addFields: {
        newdate: {$dateAdd:{
            startDate: "$basedate",
            unit: "millisecond",
            amount: {$multiply: [ "$binms", {$trunc: {$divide: ["$ms", "$binms"] }} ] }
        }}
      }},
      { $project: {
         _id:0, 
         binSize: `${i}`, 
         day: { 
           $dateToString: { 
             date: "$newdate", 
             format: "%u %j" 
           } 
         }, 
         binDate: "$newdate"
      }}
   ]).toArray().shift();
   print(ret);
}

{ "binSize":"1", "day":"7 336", "binDate":"2024-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"2", "day":"6 335", "binDate":"2024-11-30T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"3", "day":"5 334", "binDate":"2024-11-29T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"4", "day":"6 335", "binDate":"2024-11-30T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"5", "day":"6 335", "binDate":"2024-11-30T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"6", "day":"2 331", "binDate":"2024-11-26T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"7", "day":"6 335", "binDate":"2024-11-30T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"8", "day":"2 331", "binDate":"2024-11-26T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"9", "day":"5 334", "binDate":"2024-11-29T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"10", "day":"6 335", "binDate":"2024-11-30T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"11", "day":"3 332", "binDate":"2024-11-27T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"12", "day":"2 331", "binDate":"2024-11-26T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"13", "day":"6 335", "binDate":"2024-11-30T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"14", "day":"6 335", "binDate":"2024-11-30T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"15", "day":"3 325", "binDate":"2024-11-20T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"16", "day":"1 323", "binDate":"2024-11-18T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"17", "day":"1 330", "binDate":"2024-11-25T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"18", "day":"3 325", "binDate":"2024-11-20T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"19", "day":"7 336", "binDate":"2024-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"}
{ "binSize":"20", "day":"6 335", "binDate":"2024-11-30T00:00:00.000Z"}

